# What is the best way to get list of mondays in a year starting from jan-1 to Dec-31

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to get list of mondays in current year from Jan-1 to Dec-31

What is the best way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: You seem to have two questions, disguised as a single question. Which is it that you are asking? And what class of object are you expecting for the result?

Comment: @codehorse can u show how it will look in code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Simple put this way, I need to get list of all mondays in that range

Use [`Date#monday?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-monday-3F) for this :

```
require 'date'

start_date = Date.new(2013,1,1)
end_date = Date.new(2013,12,31) 
(start_date..end_date).select(&:monday?)
```

Comment: Thanks Arup, But this will pick mondays from 365 days rite?, May be I am wrong, Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: @AbibullahRahamathulah I mentioned the initial and last date in the full year.. So it will work correctly.

Comment: Hey Arup, From your answer I found a better way, Marking yours as an answer, Still I am pasting the my snippet showing the benchmark in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Arup anwer,

```
start_date = (start_date = Date.new(2003,1,1)).monday? ? start_date : start_date.next_week
end_date = Date.new(2013,12,31)
```

Benchmark

```
(start_date..end_date).select(&:monday?)

[#<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f9309191f88 @label="", @real=0.006969, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.0, @total=0.0>] 

(start_date..end_date).step(7)

[#<Benchmark::Tms:0x007f9309191da8 @label="", @real=0.00179, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.0, @utime=0.0, @total=0.0>]
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed that year will start from *Monday*.

Comment: hence I have added, .next_week which starts from monday.

Comment: This is clever, but harder to understand than Arup's answer.  You have to decide whether six milliseconds is worth the decrease in readability.

Comment: @WayneConrad, Completely agreed.